# iPhone app crashes with no log (only with distribution profile)

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, distribution, provisioning

My app crashes for some reason but I can't figure out why.

It just crashes after about 3 seconds after application is launched.

The console says:

`Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 4091.`

The program being debugged is not being run.

But it does not have problem with debug profile or developer provisioning.
( It also does not have problem with simulator. )

The crash only happens with distribution or ad-hoc provisioning in device.

The debugger also works with developer profile but not with ad-hoc(or distribution) profile.

I have tried many things I can do.

- Removed old provision files in my device, and get new ones.
- Turned off the device and on again.
- Removed distribution certification and got new one. And received another provision again.

They did not work.

Does anybody have any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved the problem. I removed all previous versions of the same application in my phone. And it works fine!

Maybe there's some kind of collision.

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when you have an ad hoc version installed and you try to run a debug version or vice versa.

You cannot run an ad hoc version in debug mode, i.e. directly from xcode. 
In case you run the ad hoc/distribution profile, the app will exit soon afterward, but it install the app in your phone. Next time you run the app by tapping the app icon in your phone, it will run the ad hoc version. But you cannot debug the ad hoc version running from xcode.